Keep zero values with GROUP BY and COUNT in mysql while having subquery in FROM
This is Problem 1907 in LeetCode.
There are two columns in Accounts table. One is account_id, and the other is income. I have to write a solution to calculate the number of bank accounts for each salary category -- "Low Salary", "Average Salary", "High Salary", and the result table must contain all three categories.
I tried to self join the derived table to obtain zero values with GROUP BY, but I don't know how to name the subquery in FROM?
SELECT a.category, count(*) as accounts_count
FROM (
    SELECT account_id, income, 
    CASE 
        WHEN income <20000 THEN 'Low Salary'
        WHEN income <=20000 AND income <= 50000 THEN 'Average Salary'
        WHEN income >50000 THEN 'High Salary'
    END AS category 
    FROM Accounts
) Accounts_category a
LEFT JOIN Accounts_category b ON a.account_id = b.account_id
GROUP BY a.category

In this code, I have an error in my SQL syntax for the FROM's alias.
I've checked the solutions in LeetCode but they all use totally different ways to solve it. I want to know if my way is possible..?

I have an error in my SQL syntax for the FROM's alias. Of course, you try to assign two aliases to your subquery ... ) Accounts_category [alias1] a [alias2] which is not correct. You use a alias in the next code, so remove Accounts_category from your code.

You don't need the left join in the outer query here.  Just aggregate over the subquery by category and generate the counts.
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS accounts_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN income < 20000 THEN 'Low Salary'
            WHEN income < 50000 THEN 'Average Salary'
            ELSE 'High Salary'
        END AS category 
    FROM Accounts
) t
GROUP BY category;

Actually, the subquery itself also isn't needed, and we can write the following more simple version:
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN income < 20000 THEN 'Low Salary'
        WHEN income < 50000 THEN 'Average Salary'
        ELSE 'High Salary'
    END AS category,
    COUNT(*) AS accounts_count
FROM Accounts
GROUP BY 1;


Thank you so much for your reply!!
But I think you kinda misunderstood my question, or i didn't express myself clearly enough. What confused me is that I don't how to show the 0 values after GROUP BY. I know a common solution is by LEFT JOIN (self join), but how can i self join the table with subquery? Maybe I should create another table?

Assuming income would never be negative or NULL, my answer should already be reporting the zero categories correctly.
